# add string after img with php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I need to add a string (in this case is a `div`) after an img tag on each post on wordpress. I know where do it but I don't know how. I tried with `preg_replace` but it doesn't work:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '/<img[^>]+\>/i <div...>', $content);
```

As result i get `/<img[^>]+\>/i <div...>` and not the img followed by .
How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace part should be: `'$0 <div...>'`, which basically sais: take what you have found with my pattern and append my div.

So your code should like:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '$0 <div...>', $content);
```

Comment: I get <div...> repeated two times and img is disappeared

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `preg_replace()` should be the replacement string, not another regular expression. You can use `$0` (the whole match) or `$1 ~ $9` for each of the memory captures you have. In your case you don't have any memory captures (stuff between parentheses), so:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+>/i', '$0 <div...>', $content);
```

*Btw, you don't have to escape the `>` in the expression.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "<img /> <br/> <img />" ;
$content = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+\>)/i', '$1 <div></div>', $content);
echo htmlentities($content) ;
```